# What exactly happens when an OS goes into kernel mode?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I find that neither my textbooks or my googling skills give me a proper answer to this question. I know it depends on the operating system, but on a general note: what happens and **why?**

My textbook says that a system call causes the OS to go into kernel mode, given that it's not already there. This is needed because the kernel mode is what has control over I/O-devices and other things outside of a specific process' adress space. But if I understand it correctly, a switch to kernel mode does not necessarily mean a process context switch (where you save the current state of the process elsewhere than the CPU so that some other process can run).

Why is this? I was kinda thinking that some "admin"-process was switched in and took care of the system call from the process and sent the result to the process' address space, but I guess I'm wrong. I can't seem to grasp what ACTUALLY is happening in a switch to and from kernel mode and how this affects a process' ability to operate on I/O-devices.

Thanks alot :)

EDIT: bonus question: does a library call necessarily end up in a system call? If no, do you have any examples of library calls that do not end up in system calls? If yes, why do we have library calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historically system calls have been issued with interrupts. Linux used the `0x80` vector and Windows used the `0x2F` vector to access system calls and stored the function's index in the `eax` register. More recently, we started using the `SYSENTER` and `SYSEXIT` instructions. User applications run in `Ring3` or userspace/usermode. The CPU is *very* tricky here and switching from kernel mode to user mode requires special care. It actually involves fooling the CPU to think it was from usermode when issuing a special instruction called `iret`. The only way to get back from usermode to kernelmode is via an interrupt or the already mentioned `SYSENTER/EXIT` instruction pairs. They both use a special structure called the `TaskStateSegment` or `TSS` for short. These allows to the CPU to find where the kernel's stack is, so yes, it essentially requires a task switch.

***But what really happens?*** 
When you issue an system call, the CPU looks for the `TSS`, gets its `esp0` value, which is the kernel's stack pointer and places it into `esp`. The CPU then looks up the interrupt vector's index in another special structure the `InterruptDescriptorTable` or `IDT` for short, and finds an address. This address is where the function that handles the system call is. The CPU pushes the flags register, the code segment, the user's stack and the instruction pointer for the next instruction that is after the `int` instruction. After the systemcall has been serviced, the kernel issues an `iret`. Then the CPU returns back to usermode and your application continues as normal.

***Do all library calls end in system calls?*** 
Well most of them do, but there are some which don't. For example take a look at `memcpy` and the rest.

Comment: Thanks alot! Great answer :) But why is switching to kernel mode so much more time-consuming than just doing a normal process context switch? Doesn't both pretty much do the same thing: swap out registers, callstack etc.?

Comment: Because hardware-assisted task switching, which uses the TSS, is required. The hardware switching is no longer updated and hence is a lot slower than software task switching.

Comment: Also the pointer to the TSS is in the GDT so it requires a lot more memory accesses as well.